# Importance sampling in monte carlo method (in C)

Tags: c, integration, montecarlo

Hiya, Ive written a code which successfully approximation one, two and three dimensional integrals using a 'crude' Monte-Carlo sampling technique.
I would now like to improve this by using 'importance sampling', as apparently this can reduce variance.  I have read a few web pages about this but none seem particularly clear.  How would I implement something like this?  Many Thanks. Jack

Comment: I'm afraid to say that the only way to figure it out in general is to understand the math. Sometimes you can figure it out for a particular case by analogy with a similar already-worked example, but there is some risk of making a bone-head error when doing that. I've never bothered with importance sampling myself, but scanning the wikipedia article suggests its not much more complicated the the basic sampling theorem.

Comment: This code in C, for approximation one, two and three dimensional integrals using a 'crude' Monte-Carlo sampling technique is available as open source?
I need to do something similar to include in an application I am developing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I found my mistake.  I wasn't using the inverse integral of the PDF to calculate the 'weight' of each point.  For anyone whos's interested my conditional loop read like:

```
for (i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    X = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
   integrand = function(inverse(X)) / PDF(inverse(X));
   sum = sum + integrand;
   sum2 = sum2 + (integrand * integrand);
}
average = sum / N;
average2 = sum2 / N;
```

Where PDF is my probability density function, inverse is the inverse integral of the PDF.  and average and average2 represent  and  respectively.